# Python-libsass doesn't recognize sass syntax?

Tags: python, libsass

I am trying to compile sass with python-libsass package, am I doing something wrong? It seems that I am using the correct sass syntax but still getting wierd errors, it wants semicolons at the end of each line, very strange:

```
> pip install libsass
> Successfully installed libsass-0.13.3
...
>>> sass.compile(string='$a: 1\n$b: 2')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sass.py", line 640, in compile
    raise CompileError(v)
sass.CompileError: Error: Invalid CSS after "$b": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ": 2"
        on line 2 of stdin
>> $b: 2
   ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you need the semicolon after each line in saas.

Take a look at the [docs](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

So, in your example it should be:

```
sass.compile(string='$a: 1;\n$b: 2;')
```

UPDATE: If you actually want to see some output from the compiler you need to use the SASS properties that you set.

Take this example:

```
print sass.compile(string='$primary_color: blue;\n a { b { color: $primary_color; } }')
```

will print out:

```
a b {
  color: blue; }
```

See how the variable *$primary_color* has been compiled to *blue* in resulting CSS